# Android listener for return key on EditText not working for every device

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent

I want to initialize a compose field with a listener for the return key. In the documentation it says that `actionId` will be `EditorInfo.IME_NULL` if it is being called due to the enter key being pressed. I compared `actionId` for that value. It also says that if triggered by a returnkey we receive `KeyEvent` object so i test it for `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP` which is the value corresponding for the release of a key. 
When i run the code it works for fine for a device running KitKat but in the other running Lollilop it doesn't consume return key and it doesn't call `onEditorAction()`. It just inserts a new line. Here's the code:

```
public void setupChat() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setupChat()");
    oETConversation.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEditorAction()");
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String s = v.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(s);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void sendMessage(String s) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "sendMessage()");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this is how I do it using `keyEvent` instead:

```
oETConversation.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                String s = oETConversation.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(s);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps;)

**UPDATE**

Make sure in your xml your editText has `android:singleLine="true"` field.

Comment: It still works for device running KitKat(but now it adds new lines on return) and it works on virtual device running API 25. On Lollipop it has the same problem, it doesn't even call the method(onkey() in this case)

Comment: Now works on Lollipop too! Still i find it intriguing that it was calling the method before and now is. What's the reason?

Comment: Because it's listening to user-input KeyEvent which is "Return" in this case. You may try keep the `android:singleLine="true"` and use the method you posted in your question to see if it's still work.

Comment: I like the  style you suggest more, it's easier to adapt to more things. Funny thing is people were suggesting to not use `android:singleLine="true"` because it is deprecated and to use `android:maxLines="1"`. I tried since it appears to be the same thing, turns out it's not. It only works with `android:single="true"`.

Comment: i am getting same issue not working any key event lister i implemented above mention but still not working.