# EditorInfoActionListener not firing

Tags: java, android

I am struggling to get the code below to work properly. I have set the oneditactionlistener and used the IME action null for what i have researched and believe is used for enter. Basically there is a textbox that has the android:inputtype "number" set. Then when the user presses enter or the check mark on their device, it is supposed to grab and start a new activity. For some reason, the oneditactionlistener never seems to fire and so userInput throws an error

```
public class hordeCalculator extends AppCompatActivity implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
public final static String testMessage = "com.example.hordeCalculator.MESSAGE";

EditText textBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horde_calculator);
    textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numToSend);
    textBox.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, daysRemaining.class);
        int userInput = Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
        myIntent.putExtra(testMessage, userInput);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //Log.d("onEditorAction", view.getText().toString());
        //Log.d("onEditorAction", textBox.getText().toString());
    }else{
        Log.d("else", "Error");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Could you copy/paste your stacktrace please?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/41260960/3579786